# New line character in iOS push notification PHP

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using below message for payload

```
$message=array(
      'title' => 'Offer is valid till 31st March',
      'body' => '₹ Free home delivery \r\n Get free home delivery at any amount'
      );
```

On iPhone its displaying the character "\r\n" inside message

is there nay way to give new line in to push notificaiton message

Comment: I saw a post that suggested \\n might work, but I have never tried it myself.

Comment: I don't know iOS, but try to use double quotes instead of single quotes (in php no escape into single-quotes).

Comment: I was also trying to do this in my app..but i didn't get success. I think, iOS  ignore the special characters of body text in banner form.

Answer (score 2):

Use `"` double quotes instead of simple quote `'`

OR

Concatenate like this :

```
'body' => '₹ Free home delivery '."\r\n".' Get free home delivery at any amount'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"body" => "₹ Free home delivery \n Get free home delivery at any amount"
```

use this one will work remember quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use just \n in double quotes. - "\n"

It is tested and works fine.